# What is the mistake with "He has went"?

Tags: word-usage

Simple question.  I just want to know what this error of usage is called?  The proper form should be "He has gone."  What usage is that proper form called?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84986/discussion-on-question-by-robert-meeker-what-is-the-mistake-with-he-has-went).